# I need to find all the commits hash in between 2 commits but log doesn't stop at the second hash

Tags: git, github, gitlab, salesforce, bitbucket

I am using

```
git log feature/Collaudo --merges --oneline --pretty=tformat:"%H" hash^..hash2~0
```

**It does start from hash1** but **doesn't stop at hash2** but it keeps printing everything.

I tried removing the ~0 and the ^, I also tried using --no-walk becuase I thought it might help.

In theory it should work, the documentation and even chatGTyouknowwhat didn't help.
They both say I should just use

```
git log feature/Collaudo --merges --oneline --pretty=tformat:"%H" hash..hash2
```

But as I said this does not work either
I tried also using 3 dots instead of 2 but it still didn't work

Comment: Sounds like you reversed the refs. What do you mean by "stop at hash2"? `hash1..hash2` **starts** at `hash2` and goes backwards until `hash1`. Not the contrary.